# Firebase cloud function returns error 429

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have the spark plan of Firebase, so the free one. I am tried to write a csv file to my firestore Db. It has 13500 records and after like 50-100 writes the cloud function which I call returns a 429 (too many requests) error. I send every record to my firebase cloud function and this function writes my data to a document. Between every request I'm waiting 5s. Does somebody know where to problem could be?

```
       export const WriteToDb = functions.region("europe-west1").https.onRequest((request, response) => {

      try {
       var recievedData:string = request.body + '';
       var splittedData = recievedData.split(",");



       var data  = {City: splittedData[0],
                      Zipcode: splittedData[1],
                      State: splittedData[2]};

      const promise = admin.firestore().collection("Cities").doc().set(data);
       promise.then( () => {
       response.send("worked");
        }).catch(() => {
         console.log("Failed in PROMISE");
           response.send("crashed");
                      });               
      } 

catch (error) {
         console.log(error);

         response.send("Failed before DB connecection");
      }
```

Comment: You are most likely just hitting the limits of the free tier. Instead of writing once per entry, can you combine them then just write one time to firebase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check https://console.firebase.google.com/

**Functions -> Logs**

Does it show?
Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions

**Functions -> Health**

Error: quota exceeded (Quota exceeded for quota group 'FunctionCallsNonbillable' and limit 'Function invocations per 100 seconds' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:'.); to increase quotas, enable billing in your project at https://console.cloud.google.com/billing?project=. Function cannot be executed.

Same Issue occurred for my cloud function and after enable billing, issue resolved.

Or try with increate Quota limits as per Google documentation

Google Firebase throttle requests.
Please Ref https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/rate-limiting

Quota metrics

A metric is a named counter for measuring a certain value over time. For example, the number of HTTP requests a service receives is a metric. A quota metric is a metric that is used for quota and rate limiting purposes. When an activity occurs with a service, one or more quota metrics may increase. When the metric value hits the predefined quota limit, the service should reject the activity with a 429 error.