# Firebase Firestore Indexes issue: Oops, indexes failed to load

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, quota

When I visit the Firebase Firestore Index page, it shows an issue as `"Oops, indexes failed to load!"`. I inspect the error and it shows `429`. When I view indexes through GCP, it shows as `Failed to load indexes: Request throttled at the client by AdaptiveThrottler`. We're in the Firebase Blaze plan and I do not see any quota limit reached. This particular account has 5 projects and all of the projects indicate this same issue. What would be the issue?

[image: screenshot of the issue]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase cloud function returns error 429](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55432950/firebase-cloud-function-returns-error-429)

Comment: Sorry, It's not solving my problem.

Comment: If you're having a problem with the Firebase console, you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) directly. Stack Overflow, as a community supported site, won't be able to fix any problems it might have.

Comment: Reached out to the firebase support. They are taking time to reply to the issue. Probably be a day or two. Not sure it's a common issue since indexes work for my personal accounts. Maybe someone has fixed it by for example configuring the quota. Let's see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*firebase here*

That looks off indeed. I can't reproduce myself, but I asked around and will post an update here when I hear back.

- 7:57 AM PT: Engineering has acknowledged the problem, and is identifying potential causes.
- 8:12 AM PT: The problem may be isolated to databases in Europe.
- 9:23 AM PT: This only affects index creation and listing operations. It does *not* affect the ability read data from or write to the database. Sorry for not mentioning that earlier, as it was the first thing we determined when the problem was reported.
- 9:29 AM PT: We've identified the root cause, which was a resource exhaustion issue in region `eur3`, and have increased resources in the region to mitigate.
- 9:49 AM PT: **This issue has been mitigated now.** If you are still seeing this problem, please [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

  The engineering team is planning work to prevent this problem from reoccurring in the future.